# You have already activated rake 0.9.6, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0. Using bundle exec may solve this

Tags: ruby, bundler

Before continue reading, I must says that I already read and tried similar questions and answers on google & stackoverflow.

My problem is that:

- bundle install or update does nothing
- gem uninstall rake refuses because rake is a default gem
- I cannot use bundle exec for all my commands

Any other idea ?!

Comment: Why can't you use bundle exec for all commands?

Comment: It seems path problem. Please make sure with path. if you are using RVM then refer this : https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: not using rvm, and bundle exec at each command does not seems sustainable

Comment: I think "gem install rake" or "bundle update rake" only work if activated version if > than requiered

Answer (score 45, accepted):

At the root of project, do:

```
gem list rake
```

You will see probably more than one version. If so, then remove the version you don't need (i.e. 0.9.6) by command:

```
gem uninstall rake
```

it will ask which version to remove. Or try doing

```
bundle update rake
```

Comment: as i said, bundle update rake does not update, and gem refuses to uninstall rake

Comment: I was getting "You have already activated rake 10.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.4. Using bundle exec may solve this." just trying to run rake routes and this command fixed it for me "bundle update rake", thank!

Comment: @nerith does this issue still persists?, if yes could you show me the backtrace or output you get while try to uninstall rake gem

Comment: yes the issue persist, all the answers are correct if "activated rake version" > "required version". In my case, it's reversed :(

Comment: Ok, I retried with the same pb for another gem, and this time it worked, I must have been confused by something else earlier.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by just doing

> gem install rake

Answer (score 6):

This solved my issue

> `bundle update rake`

Comment: This answer worked for me. The [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17475284/104223) contained steps I did not require, even though `gem list rake` does indeed produce multiple versions of rake.

Answer (score 3):

You might have old version of rake installed. In that case, use:

```
gem list rake
```

If the output shows only one version as:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.6)
```

Then simply installed the newer version

gem install rake

Comment: thanks, that worked for me (just installing the rake of needed version),

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been 2 months but just wanted to share how I solved this issue. Have you tried deleting gemfile.lock? It solves my problem:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```

Comment: it's possible, yes. As you said, it has been 2 months, the error does not occurs, and I do not know how we resolve it :(

Comment: @ANeves are you sure the activated version < requiered version ?

Comment: @nerith actually, no, it was the other way around: bigger than. Sorry, I'm sleepy.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's your base installed gem that's out of date, simply use

```
gem update rake
```